# Can't get variables from SESSION

Tags: php, session

I'm having a problem with my school project. I've asked both my teacher and classmates for help but none of them doesn't know what to do.

I've made a browser based game, and obviously it needs to have users. And this is where the problem is.

When i log in and proceed to the authenticate page, it extracts info from POST just fine, but when i insert the info into SESSION in authenticate and then go to the homepage index, it refuses to get the SESSION information and i just get an error.

NOTE, design2.php doesnt have anything to do with the log in process.

Here's the code:

Login.php

```
<?php
include_once'design2.php';
?>

<div id="center">

<form method="POST" action="authenticate.php">
User Name <input id="input" type="text" name="player" size="21">
Password <input id="input" type="password" name="password" size="21">
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Login" name="submit">

<br><br>Not Registered? <a id='underlinelink' href='register.php'>Register</a>
```

Authenticate.php

```
<?php
include_once 'connect.php';
?>
<div id="center">
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  $player=$_POST['player'];
  $password=$_POST['password'];
  $player=strip_tags($player);
  $password=strip_tags($password);
  $password=md5($password);

  $query = "select name, password from players where name='$player' and password='$password'";
  $result = mysql_query($query) or die("Could not query players");
  $result2 = mysql_fetch_array($result);
  if ($result2)
  { 
    $_SESSION['player'] = $player;

    echo "<big>Logged in successfully<br>";
    echo "<A id='underlinelink' href='index.php'>Continue</a></big>";
  }
  else
  {
   echo "<big>Wrong username or password.<A id='underlinelink' href='login.php'>Try Again</a></big>";
  }
}
?>
</div>
```

Design.php (This is on every single webpage on my site)

```
<?php
include_once 'connect.php';
?>

<link href="stilark.css" rel="stylesheet" type="css" />

<?php
session_start();  

if(isset($_SESSION['player']))
    $player = $_SESSION['player'];
else
    echo "could not logg in, <a href='login.php'>Go back</a>"; 
    exit;

$playerinfo="SELECT * from players where name='$player'";
$playerinfo2=mysql_query($playerinfo) or die("could not get player stats!");
$playerinfo3=mysql_fetch_array($playerinfo2);

?>
```

Please help, i really need to get this done before its due.

Comment: Do `session_start()` before you write in the session as well. So `session_start()` before you `$_SESSION['player'] = $player;`

Answer (score 1):

You need to create or resume the session before you write into it. So in your *Authenticate.php* where you do `$_SESSION['player'] = $player;`, create a session first exactly as you do it in your other files. Something like that

*Authenticate.php*

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'connect.php';
?>
<div id="center">
<?php

// Rest of your code
// ...

if ($result2)
{ 
    $_SESSION['player'] = $player;

// and so on...
```

Also, as @DamienLegros noted in his answer, you should always have the `session_start()` statement as early as possible in your code, i.e. as one of the first statements, so you make sure no output has been made before it's started. Otherwise you'll start getting errors stating that `headers has already been sent`.

Comment: seriously, thanks so much for the help <3 love you @havelock for your fast and accurate answers!

Comment: No problem, it's funny though, that your teacher hadn't spotted it. Well, depending on what subject he/she is teaching ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Your `session_start()` must be BEFORE any output

```
<?php
session_start(); 
include_once 'connect.php';
?>

<link href="stilark.css" rel="stylesheet" type="css" />
```

Comment: ...or input for that matter.

Comment: Genereal rule is that put your session_start as a first line after 
(of course between tags like <?php session_start(); ?>)

Comment: tried to put the session_start() first, did not work. I still get the same problem as before.

Comment: what is the error message? if this is something like "headers already sent" that means you have sent something back to the browser before starting the session.

Comment: As the title's stating "Can't get variables from SESSION" ;-) There was no mention of `headers already sent`, although that would have been next.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'connect.php';
?>
<div id="center">
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
...
...
...
```

note: add `session_start();` at the top of your `Authenticate.php` page